# window freezes when I try to show an evolving value in a Qt window using threads with python

Tags: python, multithreading, pyqt, pyqt4

My main objective is to show a constantly evolving value on a Qt-window `textEdit`. (this window contains only a `checkBox` and a `textEdit`).
Sadly, I cannot click on the checkbox and the window is frozen until I shutdown the terminal.

```
import sys
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui,uic


class MyThread(Thread):

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)

    #function to continually change the targeted value
    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 20):
            self.a = randint (1, 10)
            secondsToSleep = 1
            time.sleep(secondsToSleep)


class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow,Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mywindow.ui',self)
        self.checkBox.stateChanged.connect(self.checkeven)
        self.show()

    #i show the value only if the checkbox is checked
    def checkeven(self):
        while self.checkBox.isChecked():
            self.textEdit.setText(str(myThreadOb1.a)) 



# Run following code when the program starts
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


   # Declare objects of MyThread class
   myThreadOb1 = MyThread()
   myThreadOb2 = MyWindow()

   # Start running the threads!
   myThreadOb1.start()
   myThreadOb2.start()

   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

At the moment I'm using a thread to set a random value to `a`, but at the end it is supposed to be a bit more complex as I will have to take the values from an automation.

Do you have any clue why my code is acting like this?
Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `while self.checkBox.isChecked()` is blocking, preventing the GUI from handling other events.

Also you should not run a PyQt GUI on another thread than the main one.

If you want to send data from one thread to another, a good option is to use the signals.

Doing all these considerations we have the following:

```
import sys
from threading import Thread
from random import randint
import time
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic, QtCore


class MyThread(Thread, QtCore.QObject):
    aChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)

    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        QtCore.QObject.__init__(self)
    #function to continually change the targeted value
    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 20):
            self.aChanged.emit(randint(1, 10))
            secondsToSleep = 1
            time.sleep(secondsToSleep)


class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mywindow.ui',self)
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.aChanged.connect(self.on_a_changed, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.thread.start()
        self.show()

    #i show the value only if the checkbox is checked
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_a_changed(self, a):
        if self.checkBox.isChecked():
            self.textEdit.setText(str(a)) 



# Run following code when the program starts
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


   # Declare objects of MyThread class
   w = MyWindow()

   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

An option more to the style of Qt would be to use QThread since it is a class that handles a thread and is a QObject so it handles the signals easily.

```
import sys
from random import randint
from PyQt4 import QtGui, uic, QtCore


class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    aChanged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(int)
    def run(self):
        for i in range(1, 20):
            self.aChanged.emit(randint(1, 10))
            secondsToSleep = 1
            QtCore.QThread.sleep(secondsToSleep)


class MyWindow(QtGui.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyWindow,self).__init__()
        uic.loadUi('mywindow.ui',self)
        self.thread = MyThread()
        self.thread.aChanged.connect(self.on_a_changed, QtCore.Qt.QueuedConnection)
        self.thread.start()
        self.show()

    #i show the value only if the checkbox is checked
    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(int)
    def on_a_changed(self, a):
        if self.checkBox.isChecked():
            self.textEdit.setText(str(a)) 



# Run following code when the program starts
if __name__ == '__main__':
   app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)


   # Declare objects of MyThread class
   w = MyWindow()

   sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will look deeply into the Qthread to see what I can do with it.

Comment: Just a question however: can I also emit a signal from my main (myWindow) to the other thread? For example a push button how stop the random process when clicked.

Comment: @AlexisMonfilliette 
If you can, as I said in my answer if you want to communicate data between threads the best option is to use signals. If my answer helps you do not forget to mark it as correct please, if you do not know how to do it, check the [tour], that is the best way to thank.